# loading an external GeoJSON into Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, geojson

To get familiar with GeoJSON / Openlayers , I tried to use this example

http://gis-lab.info/share/DR/sandbox/geojson.html (found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368726/how-to-read-external-geojson-file-from-openlayers) on stackoverflow)

first step was to copy the html locally a and change the url to the geojson file from

```
"./data/l1.geojson"
```

to

```
"http://gis-lab.info/share/DR/sandbox/data/l1.geojson"
```

no other changes made, but it didn't work ..

2nd try was to just put the geojson file locally.

didn't work either

What am I missing  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try copying that data locally to `"./data/l1.geojson"` to avoid Cross-domain issues. Be aware of the browser's [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

If calling the that exists on a seperate domain is a requirement, then get the data first using Ajax, JSONP or back-end proxy then feed it into openlayers. [read up on this](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/request.html).

Comment: Thanks.. changing location and moving stuff to the server made it work.