# GeoJSON file is not loaded properly in my localhost

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson

I have also added this vector in my local host code but JSON file is not loaded.

```
geojson_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("features", {
            projection: epsg4326,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: myGeoJSON,
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            })
        });
```

I have also added JSON file:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [ 
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "GMI_ADMIN": "GBR-SCT", "FIPS_CNTRY": "UK",              
"CNTRY_NAME": "United Kingdom", "POP_RANK": 5, "ADMIN_NAME": "Scotland", "STATUS":   
"Other",    "PORT_ID": 32170, "CITY_NAME": "Dundee", "POP_CLASS": "100,000 to 250,000"   
}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -2.966700, 56.466702 ] } }
,
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "GMI_ADMIN": "GBR-SCT", "FIPS_CNTRY": "UK",   
"CNTRY_NAME": "United Kingdom", "POP_RANK": 7, "ADMIN_NAME": "Scotland", "STATUS": 
"Other", "PORT_ID": 33515, "CITY_NAME": "Hunterston", "POP_CLASS": "Less than 50,000" }, 
"geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -4.856786, 55.736744 ] } }
]}
```

Comment: Check `url` property of `protocol` object. It looks incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Vector Layer:

```
  geojson = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("features",, { 
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
            'default': {
                fillColor: '#659AB6',
                fillOpacity: 0.6,
                stroke: true,
                strokeColor: '#3D5B6B',
                strokeWidth: 3,
                pointRadius: 5
            }
        }
            ) })
```

Add Data

```
data= {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [ 
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "GMI_ADMIN": "GBR-SCT", "FIPS_CNTRY": "UK",              
"CNTRY_NAME": "United Kingdom", "POP_RANK": 5, "ADMIN_NAME": "Scotland", "STATUS":   
"Other",    "PORT_ID": 32170, "CITY_NAME": "Dundee", "POP_CLASS": "100,000 to 250,000"   
}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -2.966700, 56.466702 ] } }
,
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "GMI_ADMIN": "GBR-SCT", "FIPS_CNTRY": "UK",   
"CNTRY_NAME": "United Kingdom", "POP_RANK": 7, "ADMIN_NAME": "Scotland", "STATUS": 
"Other", "PORT_ID": 33515, "CITY_NAME": "Hunterston", "POP_CLASS": "Less than 50,000" }, 
"geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -4.856786, 55.736744 ] } }
]};
```

use jQuery Each Function (add geometry):

```
$(data.features).each(function (index, key) {//jquery
geojsonfile = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON
        geojson.addFeatures([geojsonfile.parseFeature(data.features[index])]);

});
```

Add Map Layer

```
  map.addLayer(geojson);
```